# How to pull up a value when selecting a value from a list

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

we need the help of smart people.
I have the following models

```
class PCModel(models.Model):
      PC_name = models.CharField('Названние компьютера', max_length=60)
      CPU = models.ForeignKey('CPUModel', verbose_name='Процессор', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
      GPU = models.ForeignKey('GPUModel', verbose_name='Видеокарта', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
      RAM = models.ForeignKey('RAMModel', verbose_name='Оперативная память', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,
                        null=True)
      Motherboard = models.ForeignKey(
    'MotherboardModel', verbose_name='Материнская  плата', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
)
      HDD = models.ForeignKey('HDDModel', verbose_name='HDD', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
      SSD = models.ForeignKey('SSDModel', verbose_name='SSD', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
      Power_suppy = models.ForeignKey('Power_suppyModel', verbose_name='Блок питания', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                blank=True, null=True)
      Case = models.ForeignKey('CaseModel', verbose_name='Корпус', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
      purchase_price = models.IntegerField('Стоимость покупки', default=0)
      cost_of_sale = models.IntegerField('Стоимость продажи', default=0)
      profit = models.IntegerField('Прибыль', default=0)
      slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
      sold = models.BooleanField('Статус', default=False)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.PC_name

      def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse("pcmodel_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          self.slug = self.slug
          super(PCModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and

```
class CPUModel(models.Model):
      manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=manufacturer_choice)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      number_of_cores = models.IntegerField('Количество ядер', choices=number_choice)
      number_of_threads = models.IntegerField('Количество потоков', choices=number_choice)
      base_frequency = models.IntegerField('Базовая частота', choices=frequency_choice)
      turbo_boost = models.IntegerField('Частота Turbo boost', choices=frequency_choice)
      socket = models.IntegerField('Сокет', choices=socket_choice)
      TDP = models.IntegerField('Тепловыделение (TDP)', choices=TDP_choice)
      RAM_type = models.CharField('Поддерживаемый тип памяти', choices=RAM_type_choice, max_length=5)
      purchase_price = models.IntegerField('Цена закупки')
      count = models.IntegerField('Количество')
      in_stock = models.BooleanField('Наличие', default=False)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name

      def __int__(self):
          return self.purchase_price

      def get_purchase(self):
          return self.purchase_price
```

There is a form

```
class AddPCForm(forms.ModelForm):
      CPUModel = ModelChoiceField(label='', queryset=CPUModel.objects.all(), empty_label='')

      class Meta:
          model = PCModel
          fields = [
              'PC_name', 'CPU', 'GPU', 'RAM', 'Motherboard', 'HDD', 'SSD', 'Power_suppy', 'Case', 'purchase_price', 'sold'
          ]
```

It looks like this
[image]

It is necessary to make sure that when choosing a processor, the price is automatically tied up in the price field. How can this be done?
I was thinking about CPUModel.objects.raw(SQL query), will it work? Maybe someone else knows how to implement it.
It is necessary that when choosing a processor(процессор), its price is automatically pulled up in the price(цена) field.

Answer (score 1):

With Django it is not recommended to use raw SQL for security reasons. It is assumed to be on the web. To effectively manage dynamic choices, I recommend you study the HTMX js library. It sends requests to the server and renders responses in html. It has all the tools to update your choices based on events. Naturally, it does not require refreshing the page.
A little effort to study it, it's worth it.
otherwise you have to write some javascript code